# Java Getting Null when doing class.getResource on empty directory

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am writing a spring maven web application.
In my code I am trying to do various operations on file and directories located at classpath.

For ex - Below snippet to get all files in directory

```
{
    URL resource = FileUtil.class.getResource(inboxLocation); //getting null when directory is empty
    File directory = new File(resource.getPath());
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(directory, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, null);
    ArrayList<File> fileArray = new ArrayList<>(files);
    return fileArray.subList(0, Math.min(batchSize, fileArray.size()));
}
```

This works fine when inboxLocation(a directory) already has a file. 
But when the inboxLocation is empty, I am getting null in resource.

There is another function where I try to move file to a directory..
Even that method fails when directory is Empty.

I am using IntelliJ as the platform for development.

Can anyone help on how to handle this scenario..
Any help is appreciated

Comment: IntelliJ has nothing to do with your problems.  You should be thinking in terms of streams, not files.  Your web app shouldn't depend on access to the file system.

Comment: I agree.. I am doing this just to setup the proper test env

Comment: Why you have to use `getResource` to get the `File` object?

Comment: My application is somewhat simulation of SMTP over file system. So for unit tests, I am trying to use temp folders at classpath. So in order to access directories over classpath, I am using getResource... which helps to read both from relative classpath and absolute location..

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of getResource is to [read resources from a JAR file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html).  Note that [a resource is data (images, audio, text, and so on)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html), a directory is not a resource.

Use [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) to get a stream of a directories entries.

Comment: The implied restriction is not correct. The resource linked is discussing resource loading in context of a web container so naturally the classloader involved will be the web container's and per JEE standard jar, war, or ear archives will be searched. See [Class#gerResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)